# How to make TypeScript literal types in Angular (narrow from string to specific strings)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I made a set of radio buttons:

[image]

```html
<mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="learningMode" aria-label="Select an learning mode">
    <mat-radio-button value="videos">Videos
            <mat-icon>videocam</mat-icon>
    </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="vocabulary">Vocabulary
            <mat-icon>feed</mat-icon>
    </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="wordSearch">Word Search
            <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
    </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

It works just great if I set `learningMode` as a `string`.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  learningMode: string = 'videos';
}
```

The [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) says that I can narrow `string` to a Literal Type, i.e., three strings:

```js
s: string, alignment: "left" | "right" | "center"
```

But this doesn't work:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
   learningMode: string, learningModes: 'videos' | 'vocabulary' | 'wordSearch' = 'videos';
}
```

How do I narrow `learningMode` from any string to any of three strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand corectly. There is my aproach how to narrow learningMode.

```
export declare type LearningModes = 'videos' | 'vocabulary' | 'wordSearch';
```

and after that i would say

```
 learningMode: LearningModes;
```

You cannot use = (equal) in declaring type. So there should be some method (function) to handle this logic. For example with if else statement.

```
 example(test: string){
   if (test === 'videos'){
      return 'wordSearch'
    }
  }
```

Comment: That worked! As you said, the variable isn't initialized when declared so I set it in ngOnIt(). I'll write an answer showing the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax that you're using for declaring is kind off wrong.

```
learningMode: 'videos' | 'vocabulary' | 'wordSearch' = 'videos';
//where videos will be default value
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete solution.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export declare type LearningModes = 'videos' | 'vocabulary' | 'wordSearch';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  learningMode: LearningModes;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.learningMode = 'videos';
  }

}
```